# Is it good have a DatabaseManager with all of the functions from all the model objects?

Tags: java, android, database-design, ormlite

I'working on a db application with ORmlite, my model is like this:

MDL object..

```
DatabaseTable(tableName = "UserCars")
public class CarMDL
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int _id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    private String _name;

//................. etc
}

// DB Helper class...

public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
{
    private Dao<CarMDL,Integer> _carDao = null;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database,ConnectionSource connectionSource)
    {
        try 
        {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, CarMDL.class);

        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

  public Dao<CarMDL, Integer> getCarDao() 
    {
        if (null == _carDao) 
        {
            try 
            {
                _carDao = getDao(CarMDL.class);

            }catch (java.sql.SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return _carDao;
    }

}

// DatabaseManager class...

public class DatabaseManager
{
    static private DatabaseManager  instance;

    private DatabaseHelper  helper;


    static public void init(Context ctx)
    {
        if (null == instance)
        {
            instance = new DatabaseManager(ctx);
        }
    }

    static public DatabaseManager getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseManager(Context ctx)
    {
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }

    private DatabaseHelper getHelper()
    {
        return helper;
    }

// All the Dao functions of all MDL objects are in this class, for example:

public List<CarMDL> getAllCars()
    {
        List<CarMDL> carLists = null;
        try
        {
            carLists = getHelper().getCarDao().queryForAll();
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return carLists;
    }

// This is another MDL object..

public List<MarkMDL> getAllMarks()
    {
        List<MarkMDL> marks = null;
        try
        {
            marks = getHelper().getMarkDao().queryForAll();
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return marks;       
    }

}
```

So my question is, is it good have a DatabaseManager with all the functions from all the model objects, like:

```
listCarById(int id)
listPlaneById(int id)
removeCar(int id)
removePlane(int id)
```

Etc.....

Answer (score 3):

Updated per Gray's comment.

Be careful with your "singleton" implementation. Your `init` method should be `synchronized` to ensure that you don't end up with multiple instances of your `DatabaseManager` class due to concurrency issues. I would just combine the `init` and `getInstance` methods to the following (note the added [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) keyword):

```
public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance(Context c)
{
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new DatabaseManager(c);

    return instance;
}
```

For further reading, check out these blog posts about [Single SQLite Connection](http://www.touchlab.co/blog/single-sqlite-connection/) and [Android Sqlite locking](http://www.touchlab.co/blog/android-sqlite-locking/) by Kevin Galligan (one of the [contributors](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_8.html) to ORMlite).

**Update:**

To answer your question about how to organize your loading methods like `getAllCars`, I would first suggest making them `static`, since they do not depend on anything else besides your method to get your singleton of `DatabaseManager`, which of course, would also be `static`. If you have a small number of these types of methods, you could make them all static members of `DatabaseManger`. If you have many, you could make a helper class for all static methods corresponding to a type.

If you have a method that **does** depend on the internals of a given instance of `CarMDL` or `MarkMDL` (like you need a method to get some associated references), consider making these methods members of the `CarMDL` or `MarkMDL` class.

Comment: I actually do not have a problem with the locally cached DAO instances.  Looking them up in the DaoManager requires an object creation and there is no penalty that I can see.  That's the pattern that all of the example objects use.

Comment: ok, combining init and getInstance looks nice! But I'm not sure to put all the models functions in a single class, would be better to create another DAOs that extends an interface with some common methods? but I´m not sure how this could be...I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

I put all my one-time-per-app work in Application onCreate and I keep a reference of the application instance itself, so I can do many tasks without having to mess with synchronized methods or similar. So let's say we have an Application (remember to add it in the manifest):

```
public class App extends Application
{
    private static App gInstance = null;
    // your static globals here

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // according to documentation onCreate is called before any other method
        super.onCreate();
        // assign here all your static stuff
        gInstance = this;
    }

    // doesn't need to be synchronized because of the early onCreate
    public static App getInstance()
    {
        return gInstance;
    }
}
```

then your database helper class, Manifest.class is an array of all of your datatype classes:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
{
    // private constructor, singleton pattern, we use
    // App context so the class is created on static init
    private static DatabaseHelper gHelper = new DatabaseHelper(App.getInstance());

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);

        // cache your dao here
        for (Class<?> cls: Manifest.classes)
        {
            try
            {
                DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), cls);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // if you need the instance, you don't need synchronized because of static init
    public static DatabaseHelper getHelper()
    {
        return gHelper;
    }

    // lookup from cache
    public static <D extends Dao<T, ?>, T> D getTypeDao(Class<T> cls)
    {
        return DaoManager.lookupDao(gHelper.getConnectionSource(), cls);
    }

    // we leak this class here since android doesn't provide Application onDestroy
    // it's not really a big deal if we need the orm mapping for all application lifetime
    // Q: should I keep the instance closeable? the android finalyzer calls somehow close here? I was unable to reproduce, to be sure you can call the super.close() and print a warning
    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("DatabaseHelper Singleton is ethernal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

addd the context to your DatabaseManager method

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseManager.init(this.getContext());
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
```

example android app with ormlite
https://github.com/elberthcabrales/cfeMedicion